# How can I insert HTML & JavaScript code from another file?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is my first question on SO. So please be patient with me.

I'm creating a very small web page that has an basic HTML structure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>BootVid</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.3.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.3.0/video.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .fakeimg {
            height: 200px;
            background: #aaa;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div id="pageContent">
            <!--Page Content Goes Here-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            routeTo("videoplayer");
        });

        function routeTo(path) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', 'components/' + path + '.html', true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState !== 4) return;
                if (this.status !== 200) return; // or whatever error handling you want
                document.getElementById('pageContent').innerHTML = this.responseText;
            };
            xhr.send();
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

So this is basically an empty webpage with a PAGE CONTENT div, that I load HTML code from a seperate `.html` file into the `pageContent` div on the "main" page.

The basic routing works 100% good. But when I load external html from one of the `.html` files, the HTML displays fine but the JavaScript code is never getting executed. How do I inject HTML code into a div, along with JavaScript code that needs to execute on load?

Here is an example of a page I need to load in the `pageContent` div, that initializes a VideoJS instance.

```
<!--videoplayer.html-->
<div class="container mt-5" id="vidPlayer" hidden>
    <div class="mx-auto col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
        <video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none">
            <source id="video-source" src=".mp4" type="video/mp4"> <!--video/mp4 application/x-mpegURL-->
        </video>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var player = videojs('my-video', {
        repsonsive: true,
        inactivityTimeout: 2000
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can extract the script file and add it to the head of the current document.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide an example of how this would be achieved? Just a basic example. Will adjust for my use case. Thank you for the reply

Comment: I [just did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76744878/295783)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the script elements from the pageContent div, clone them and append them to document.head. You just only have to change your `routeTo` function.

Your `routeTo` function will become like this :

```
function routeTo(path) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'components/' + path + '.html', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState !== 4) return;
        if (this.status !== 200) return; // or whatever error handling you want
        document.getElementById('pageContent').innerHTML = this.responseText;
        /* Loop For The Scripts Inside The pageCont DIV */
        for (script of document.getElementById('pageContent').querySelectorAll('script')) {
            var scriptElem = document.createElement('script');
            if (script.src !== '' && typeof script.src !== 'undefined') {
                scriptElem.src = script.src;
            } else {
                scriptElem.innerHTML = script.innerHTML;
            }
            
            /* Remove the old script from pageContent div */
            script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
            
            /* Check if scriptElem exists or not */
            var scriptExists = (function() {
                for (elem of document.querySelectorAll('script')) {
                    if (elem.outerHTML === scriptElem.outerHTML) return true;
                }
                return false;
            })();
            
            /* If script doesn't exists, append it to the head */
            if (!scriptExists) {
             document.head.appendChild(scriptElem);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

This even supports external scripts (i.e. scripts with src attribute set to another JavaScript file).

Now, it will prevent script duplication and remove the script from the `pageContent` div once the script is appended to the head.

Comment: `document.getElementById('pageContent').querySelectorAll('script')).forEach(script =>  { let scriptElem = document.createElement('script'); if (script.src !== '' && typeof script.src !== 'undefined') { scriptElem.src = script.src; } else { scriptElem.textContent = script.textContent; }  document.head.appendChild(scriptElem); };`

Comment: @mplungjan, Yeah, `forEach` would've been shorter, but it is deprecated in Firefox 68, and removed since Firefox 71.

Comment: So after testing, most everything works. Only thing I can think will become an issueis that the scripts are not removed when going through multiple pages. Thus it ends up with multiple copies of the same script trying to initialize the same code. Any ideas on how this can be avoided?

Comment: @CodemasterUnited You are incorrect. You MAY be thinking about the `for each` which I never even heard about until you made me look. _The for each construction is an extension to the ECMAScript language; it is defined in the E4X specification which is not widely supported._ `for (script of document.getElementById('pageContent').querySelectorAll('script'))` is super clunky

Comment: @WernerVenter, I've edited the code to prevent script duplications and now, it also removes the scripts from the `pageContent` div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  script which will test if JS is already loaded.

I have not tested it live. I may do so one of these days since it is intriguing

```js
const head = document.querySelector("head");
const scriptIsLoaded = (script, src) => {
  const pageScripts = document.querySelectorAll('script');
  if (src) {
    // this may need some testing (pageScripts src="jquery.js", script src="https://....jQuery.js"
    return pageScripts.find(pageScript => pageScript.src.endsWith(script));
  }
  return pageScripts.find(pageScript => pageScript.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, "") === script.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, "")); // compare text with all whitespace removed.
}
const routeTo = (path) => {
  const url = `components/${path}.html`;
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((html) => {
      // Convert the HTML string into a document object
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
      document.getElementById('pageContent').innerHTML = html; // load the page
      // Get the script files
      doc.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(script => {
        const src = script.src;
        if (src) {
          if (scriptIsLoaded(src, true)) return; // already loaded
          let scriptObject = document.createElement("script");
          scriptObject.src = src;
          head.appendChild(scriptObject)
        } else {
          const text = script.textContent;
          if (text) {
            if (scriptIsLoaded(scriptObject)) return; // textContent already in a script
            let scriptObject = document.createElement("script");
            scriptObject.textContent = scriptObject.textContent;
            head.appendChild(scriptObject)
          }
        }
      });
    }).catch(function(err) {
      // There was an error
      console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
    });
};
```